# JMeter: Why JMeter ignores "&" from CSV?

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter

I have created a script in JMeter where it fetches Login credentials from CSV.

UserName: pshah

Password: Welcome&1

When I execute the script, I can see value in POST as:

UserName: pshah

**But Password: Welcome**

I would like to know why "&" is ignored from CSV.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Http Request element, in parameters table check the encode checkbox as & is a reserved character in HTTP request.

Note you can debug by using a DebugSampler and replace name by ${UserName},${Password} where UserName and Password are your variable names. Use a View Results Tree to see if the issue is in loading the CSV or somewhere else

It appears there's a bug in the HTTP Renderer of the Request. As & is a separator of HTTP Request, it appears JMeter decodes the encoded value "Welcome%261" before showing parameters, this leads to presence of 1 parameter:

[image]

While the RAW one is OK:

[image]

So it's just a Display issue in HTTP renderer , you can ignore it as RAW shows the correct request is sent.

I opened bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58413

Comment: It did not work, still I can see value passed as "Welcome" after checking "Encode" in HTTP Request Parameter.

Comment: I tested it works for me even without checking, can you show what you're doing in Test Plan ? And how you see Welcome&1 is not transmitted ? Thanks

Comment: Please check for the screenshot I just added to my question.

Comment: Thanks UBIK, I understood the issue now.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the 1 in the password Welcome&1 is showing up in the parameter name in the View result tree. 
Check the values of userName and Password in the raw tab of View Result Tree in Jmeter ,which correctly shows Welcome&1

[image]

Check the response of your request, If it is successful then the username and password are passed correctly.

Comment: I can see Post data as :                                 POST data:
UserName=pshah&Password=Welcome%261

Comment: what is the response code and response content? The "&" is not being ignored by Jmeter. Can you elaborate what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Responsecode is:             <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

Comment: I am creating just a single login script in JMeter.

Comment: As an alternative , you can record the requests for login using the test script recorder. Follow the instructions [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) and then replace the username and password using variables from CSV file.